# animation.hasEnded doesn't work as I expect. Why?

Tags: android, animation

In my app, I have an animation. I want to wait until the animation finish to continue the rest of the codes. I am trying to use .hasEnded as follows but doesn't work. I know there are some other technics to achieve this but I want to know what's wrong with this code. It is going into the endless loop at while loop

```
myplayer= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.myanim1);
    textView_title.setAnimation(myplayer);
    
    while (!myplayer.hasEnded()){
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a new Thread to test the `hasEnded`:

```
        Animation myplayer= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.myanim1);
        .....
        //start the animation

        Thread thread = new Thread(){
             @Override
             public void run() {
                 super.run();
                 boolean flag = true;
                 while (flag){
                     try {
                         Thread.sleep(1000);
                     } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                         e.printStackTrace();
                     }
                     Log.d(TAG, "run: " + myplayer.hasEnded());
                     if(myplayer.hasEnded()){
                         flag = false;
                     }
                 }
             }
         };
         thread.start();
```

[image]

---

could use the following code to listen of Animation:

```
    Animation myplayer= AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(),R.anim.myanim1);
        myplayer.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

            }
        });
    textView_title.setAnimation(myplayer);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know this technic. I just wanted to learn why .hasEnded doesn't work. What .hasEnded is doing realy?

Comment: hey@ucanbizon ,i updated the code,pls kindly refer